# How does alias in grunt-browserify really work?

Tags: javascript, configuration, gruntjs, browserify

I've read the official documentation on the `alias` option configuration in grunt-browserify, but still don't fully understand the semantics of the array one is expected to provide as a value.

With

```
alias: ["pathA:pathB"]
```

What goes to the left of the colon, and what goes to the right?

And what does this mean? (grunt-browserify doesn't complain, but what's it doing?)

```
alias: ["pathA:"]
```

Are there other configurations of alias like the last one that are not documented?

Thanks much!

Comment: Your code looks quite confusing. You cannot use semicolon in array...Didn't you meant `alias: ['pathA:pathB']` ? Docs are quite clear on using aliases ... *Aliases should be specified as fileName:alias. Filenames are parsed into their full paths with path.resolve. Module names will be required directly.*

Comment: So you still don't understand? Which part ? Before semicolon you have filename (physical file to reference) and after semicolon is actual alias that you can use with `require()` call.